# Image Processing using Gabor Filter

Tags: matlab

I am trying to execute gabor filter on images.

```
%% Read

clear all;
close all;
clc;
I=imread('test.png');
imshow(I);

%% Crop
I2 = imcrop(I);
figure, imshow(I2)
m=size(I2,1);
n=size(I2,2);
%% Gabor
phi = 7*pi/8;
theta = 2;
sigma = 0.65*theta;
for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        xprime= j*cos(phi);
        yprime= i*sin(phi);
        K = exp(2*pi*theta*i(xprime+ yprime));
        G= exp(-(i.^2+j.^2)/(sigma^2)).*abs(K);
    end
end

%% Convolve

for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
       J(i,j)=conv2(I2,G);
    end
end
imshow(uint8(J))
```

I am getting this error always.

```
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Not sure how to solve this...[image]

[image]

Comment: What is "J"? Remember that conv2 will return a matrix here, but you are trying to store it inside J(i,j).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `*` in `K = exp(2*pi*theta*i(xprime+ yprime));` between `i` and the parentheses. You like should be `K = exp(2*pi*theta*i*(xprime+ yprime));`. It is because of such cases Mathworks recommends using `sqrt(-1)` for the imaginary number.

Update:
You don't need a loop to do convolution in Matlab. You simply say `J=conv2(I2,G);`

Update 2:

Here's the working code

```
%% Gabor
phi = 7*pi/8;
theta = 2;
sigma = 0.65*theta;
filterSize = 6;

G = zeros(filterSize);


for i=(0:filterSize-1)/filterSize
    for j=(0:filterSize-/filterSize
        xprime= j*cos(phi);
        yprime= i*sin(phi);
        K = exp(2*pi*theta*sqrt(-1)*(xprime+ yprime));
        G(round((i+1)*filterSize),round((j+1)*filterSize)) = exp(-(i^2+j^2)/(sigma^2))*K;
    end
end

%% Convolve

J = conv2(I2,G);
imshow(imag(J));
```

Comment: thanks firstly for replying. but after i corrected that i had another error. 
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
Any idea?

Comment: thanks once again. but now i get a black image as output. I dun get any gabor features at all...

Comment: an image with gabor features.

Comment: What do you mean by Gabor features? Have you got a link to the book or paper you're working on?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3491/discussion-between-cnn-lakshmen-and-phonon)

Comment: @Phonon: instead of `sqrt(-1)` you can write `1i` or `1j` to denote the imaginary number

Comment: Are you sure that this code is correct ? i updated it and it works fine. But you are used these specific value of phi? i cannot use phi=0? and theta=90 ? and why sigma=0.65*theta ? where the values of aspect ratio and lambda etc ? please answer me:) i need your help

Comment: Is it the correct equation for the gabor filter ? There is a difference between this equation and the other asked in http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11448/apply-gabor-filter-to-an-input-image-using-matlab ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers above, the final code being :

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
I=imread('test.png');
imshow(I);

%% Crop
I2 = imcrop(I);
figure, imshow(I2)

    phi = 7*pi/8;
    theta = 2;
    sigma = 0.65*theta;
    filterSize = 6;

    G = zeros(filterSize);

    for i=(0:filterSize-1)/filterSize
        for j=(0:filterSize-1)/filterSize
            xprime= j*cos(phi);
            yprime= i*sin(phi);
            K = exp(2*pi*theta*sqrt(-1)*(xprime+ yprime));
            G(round((i+1)*filterSize),round((j+1)*filterSize)) = exp(-(i^2+j^2)/(sigma^2))*K;
        end
    end

    J = conv2(I,G);
    figure(2);
    imagesc(imag(J))
```