# Cropping face in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need a Matlab code that will crop the face from an image of person. I have been searching google for past 3 days but unable to find a code that works correctly. Can someone please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You may read about [wavelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet), I don't believe you were "searching google for 3 days".

[Image Processing using Gabor Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419409/image-processing-using-gabor-filter)

---

In case you have license to the [vision toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking.html):

```
% Create a cascade detector object.
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();

% Read a video frame and run the detector.
videoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader('visionface.avi');
videoFrame      = step(videoFileReader);
bbox            = step(faceDetector, videoFrame);

% Draw the returned bounding box around the detected face.
videoOut = insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame,'rectangle',bbox,'Face');
figure, imshow(videoOut), title('Detected face');
```

The code above will output the following detection. Please note that the algorithm doesn't recognize the 2 faces in the picture behind the Mathwork engineer nor his own face on the lcd screen to his right:

[image]